# How to access a JavaScript object globally

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating a JavaScript based game with PHP, and need help storing the user's account object. Once I construct the player object in JavaScript, how can I use this object throughout every page?

I have tried to add the user's account object to the window object, but did not have any luck. This code is placed in the menu which is used on all pages.

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
        $user = $_SESSION['user'];
        echo '<script>                 
        if (typeof window.user != "undefined") {
            console.log("user is defined from before.");
            console.log(window.user);
        } else {
            var user = new Player('.$user->{'id'}.',"'.$user->{'username'}.'");
            window.user = user;
            console.log("A new user was created.");
            console.log(window.user);
        }</script>';
 }
```

Each time a page is loaded, a new player is created and added to the window object. I expected "window.user" to be defined after adding the user's account object.

Here is my Player object constructor as well

```
function Player (id, username) {
this.id = id,
this.username = username,
this.resources = {
    hydrogen: 0,
    helium: 0,
    carbon: 0,
    nitrogen: 0,
    oxygen: 0,
    sodium: 0,
    magnesium: 0,
    aluminium: 0,
    silicon: 0,
    sulfur: 0,
    calcium: 0,
    titanium: 0,
    cobalt: 0,
    nickel: 0,
    copper: 0,
    krypton: 0,
    palladium: 0,
    silver: 0,
    platinum: 0,
    gold: 0
},
this.currency = {
    currency1: 0,
    currency2: 0,
    currency3: 0,
    currency4: 0,
    currency5: 0
},
this.starter = 0
```

}

Comment: Why not just make use of `localStorage` / `sessionStorage`? :)

Comment: If the user reloads the page or navigates to a different one, anything defined is lost. You should use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: Could you provide us with the player class so that we can see how to properly store the object in localstorage?

Comment: I have added my Player object constructor. It seems like localStorage is the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use local storage to store value:

```
localStorage.setItem('test', 1);
```

And get the value later:

```
localStorage.getItem('test')
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have achieved what I wanted to do.